# Thread-safe running mean and variance

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, multiprocessing

In one of my personal python libraries I have a custom class used for computing the running average and variance of a stream of numbers:

```
import numpy as np


class RunningStatsVariable:
    def __init__(self, ddof=0, parallel=None):
        self.mean = 0
        self.var = 0
        self.std = 0

        self._n = 0
        self._s = 0
        self._ddof = ddof

        if parallel == 'multiprocessing':
            from multiprocessing import Lock
            self._lock = Lock()
        elif parallel == 'threading':
            from threading import Lock
            self._lock = Lock()
        else:
            self._lock = None

    def update(self, values):
        if self._lock:
            self._lock.acquire()

        values = np.array(values, ndmin=1)
        n = len(values)

        self._n += n

        delta = values - self.mean
        self.mean += (delta / self._n).sum()

        self._s += (delta * (values - self.mean)).sum()
        self.var = self._s / (self._n - self._ddof) if self._n > self._ddof else 0
        self.std = np.sqrt(self.var)

        if self._lock:
            self._lock.release()

    def update_single(self, value):
        if self._lock:
            self._lock.acquire()

        self._n += 1

        old_mean = self.mean
        self.mean += (value - old_mean) / self._n

        self._s += (value - old_mean) * (value - self.mean)
        self.var = self._s / (self._n - self._ddof) if self._n > self._ddof else 0
        self.std = np.sqrt(self.var)

        if self._lock:
            self._lock.release()

    def __str__(self):
        if self.std:
            return f"(μ ± σ): {self.mean} ± {self.std}"
        else:
            return f"{self.name}: {self.mean}"

    def __len__(self):
        return self._n
```

The idea is to make the class safe for parallel updates, regardless of the type of parallelism used (threading or multiprocessing), and regardless of which method of updating (single-value or list) is used. The code is also available on [Replit](https://replit.com/@matedevita/ParallelSafeVariable). The below test seems to show this code works as expected:

```
data = [(np.random.random(), np.random.rand(20)) for _ in range(1000)]

def _update(var, value, arr):
    var.update_single(value)
    var.update(arr)

v1 = RunningStatsVariable()
for v, a in data:
    _update(v1, v, a)

from joblib import Parallel, delayed

v2 = RunningStatsVariable(parallel='multiprocessing')
Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(
    delayed(_update)(v2, v, a)
    for v, a in data
)

v3 = RunningStasVariable(parallel='threading')
Parallel(n_jobs=-1, prefer='threads')(
    delayed(_update)(v3, v, a)
    for v, a in data
)

# Can't use x == y == z for float comparison, so we use np.allclose instead
print(np.allclose(v1.mean, [v2.mean, v3.mean]))  # True
print(np.allclose(v1.var, [v2.var, v3.var]))     # True
print(np.allclose(v1.std, [v2.std, v3.std]))]))  # True
```

However, in parallelism testing is usually not enough to guarantee correctness. So are the updates really parallel-safe? I don't necessarily care about the parallel-safety of the `__len__` and `__str__` methods.

Also, is locking at the start of the update method and unlocking at the end good practice or should I use more specific locks?

Additionally, I would like this code to work for other people, who may not be using `joblib` for their parallelism needs. Are there other lock types I should consider?